# App Maker RadioGroup styling not working

Tags: css, google-app-maker

I would like to change the items in a Google App Maker RadioGroup from black to white.  I tried the following but it does not work:

```
.app-RadioGroup-Item {
  color: white;
}
```

I also tried .app-RadioGroup-Input, no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change labels and input colors you can try these snippets:

```css
/* This style will affect only MyRadioGroup widget on the MyPage  */
.app-MyPage-MyRadioGroup-Item>label {
  color: green;
}

.app-MyPage-MyRadioGroup-Item>input {
  border-color: red;
}

.app-MyPage-MyRadioGroup-Item>input:checked {
  border-color: red;
}

.app-MyPage-MyRadioGroup-Item>input:checked:after {
  background-color: red;
}

 /* This style will affect all RadioGroup widgets in the app  */
.app-RadioGroup-Item>label {
  color: green;
}

.app-RadioGroup-Item>input {
  border-color: red;
}

.app-RadioGroup-Item>input:checked {
  border-color: red;
}

.app-RadioGroup-Item>input:checked:after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**Note:** these styles will override styles for disabled state.

Comment: Say, is there something similar to make the radio group selector white also?  I tried .app-RadioGroup-Item>input but no luck.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the exhaustive list.